# Finding and removing duplicate indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thoughts on index creation for SQL Server for missing indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443881/thoughts-on-index-creation-for-sql-server-for-missing-indexes)
>   [T-SQL for finding Redundant Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283666/t-sql-for-finding-redundant-indexes)

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have a database with more than 150 tables that have duplicate indexes.

I found some sql scripts which will list the duplicate indexes, but I'm not sure if I should trust them.  Supposedly, they are saying that I have over 400 duplicate indexes; I'm not sure if that is correct, and therefore don't want to use them to automatically remove dupes.

How can I definitively locate duplicate indexes and remove them?

Comment: Cleaned up in prep for migration, but you have two decent answers already.  Can you try them out?  I'd rather not migrate if you have an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Will:Great Thanks i have already tried both of them. But i am still waiting for the perfect answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Tom LaRock's excellent [How to Find Duplicate Indexes](http://thomaslarock.com/2010/08/how-to-find-duplicate-indexes/) blog post - he explains in great detail how to go about, and also offers up scripts to detect duplicate indices.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code segment which will show duplication index and second query will return you script for the same . You just have to provide table name . For Example 
set @TableName = 'SalaryMaster'
this can be done by using while loop on

```
select name from sys.tables
```

put it into temp table apply while loop and execute following code

```
declare @TableName as varchar(50)

set @TableName = 'EmployeeMaster'
--- 1. 
select name as IndexName,Index_id as IndexID from sys.indexes 
where index_id  NOT in (
select MIN(index_id)  from (
select avg(column_id) avgCol,index_id  from sys.index_columns where
 object_id = object_id(@TableName)
group by index_id 
) as a group by avgCol  
) and object_id = object_id(@TableName)

--- 2.     
select '
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'''+@TableName+''') 
AND name = N'''+name+''')
DROP INDEX ['+name+'] ON '+@TableName+' WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
' from sys.indexes 
where index_id  NOT in (
select MIN(index_id)  from (
select avg(column_id) avgCol,index_id  from sys.index_columns where
 object_id = object_id(@TableName)
group by index_id 
) as a group by avgCol  
) and object_id = object_id(@TableName)
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working correctly. I tried & it has ignored some of the duplicate indexes.

Comment: Yakub , can u please elaborate on duplicate index . Above query will give u indexes having same column names . thats it . do u want like this or different .

Comment: I have two indexes  both on the same columns column1 + column2, the columns included in both the indexes are different, so i guess it should be listed in the duplicate list.

Comment: yakub sys.indexes  is a system view which list all indexes in database                   sys.index_columns list all indexes with column name